# Why is useRef and scrollIntoView ruining my margin?

Tags: css, reactjs, margin, js-scrollintoview

I'm creating a React chat app. The message history is in a `ul`, which is in a div with a `margin-top: 20px`. I'm now trying to have the app scroll to the bottom whenever a message is received. I've tried adding the following element as the last item in the `ul`:

```
const AlwaysScrollToBottom = () => {
    const elementRef = useRef()
    useEffect(() => elementRef.current.scrollIntoView())
    return <div ref={elementRef} />
}
```

This has the desired effect of always making the last message visible. However, this code is now somehow causing the div containing the ul to snap to the top of the body, with no margin. If I open developer tools, I can see the `margin-top` still active - if I disable it and re-enable it, the location of the div is corrected, but it's reset whenever I send a message.

Can someone explain how this is affecting the margin-top on the outer div? What I basically want to do is to find the last element in the list, and do

```
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight
```

but I want to do it *without using ReactDom.findNode(this)*

Thanks.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a minimal CodeSandbox example? I can't get this issue https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-kirch-1cyet?file=/src/App.js